# OS X Server: Using wsgi Python on Non-Standard Ports

Tags: python, macos, wsgi

I'm working with a simple website (a few html files and one Python script) that's running on my LAN.  In Chrome I can pull up the HTML files and Python scripts through port 80, as normal and I am using WSGIScriptAlias commands in /Library/Server/Web/Config/apache2/httpd_wsgi.conf that are working and I've set up the site and specified for it to be allowed to use Python apps through the Server GUI application.

For several reasons, I'm using a different port number for this site.  If I go to http://mycomputer.lan:1234/myfile.html, I can see the HTML file.  But if I go to http://mycomputer.lan:1234/MyWSGIApplicationScript, the server (the latest version, got it installed today) reports:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /LandSearch was not found on this server.

I've seen this work before, on other servers and I remember setting it up and getting it working on another system running OS X so the wsgi scripts worked fine on a non-standard port, but I don't have access to the notes and information I had at that time.  That makes me suspect it's probably a simple configuration option I need to change for the server to find and use the Python scripts from a different port.

What do I need to reconfigure to get it to use wsgi scripts on a non-standard port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even AppleCare didn't have an answer for this one.

When I first set up the site, I enabled the 'Python "Hello World" app at /wsgi'.  This is in the advanced settings:

[image: OS X Server Website Settings]

I did that just for testing, so when I set up the site again, I didn't bother with it.  It turns out that this one setting does more than enable one wsgi application.  It turns out that, by default, the file /Library/Server/Web/Config/apache2/httpd_wsgi.conf is not read by Apache while setting up a virtual host.  But checking the box to enable this one wsgi webapp means that the following line:

```
Include /Library/Server/Web/Config/apache2/httpd_wsgi.conf
```

will be included in the configuration file for this particular virtual host.  Any scripts aliases defined with the WSGIScriptAlias command in that file will now be available to your website, no matter what port your website is on.